# How can I store my cakephp project in git?

Tags: php, git, cakephp, composer-php, cakephp-3.0

I would like to store my new project in my company's git repo. The project will use cakephp 3. But frequently after setting up a project and pushing it I get some trouble: A coworker clones the project to his pc and it comes with missing directories (mostly "vendor"), and we frequently get problems with debug kit (need to remove the database file after every git pull).

Is there some recommended procedure to create this kind of project?

Comment: Does your project have a ```.gitignore``` file? If so, folders such as vendor won't show up on GitHub (or whatever version control tool you use)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The recommended strategy for composer-backed PHP projects is as follows:

- Add the vendor directory to gitignore.
- Commit composer.json and composer.lock.

When your colleague begins development they just need to run `composer install`, and the committed composer.lock file will result in the right dependencies being downloaded.

Comment: So just to be sure about the path I have to follow:
    - Install cakephp using composer, the way the official documentation shows;
     - git init the project's main directory;
     - add vendor to main directory's .gitignore;
     - git add all, check if composer.json and composer.lock are included;
     - git commit & push;
     - coworker pulls, then run composer install.

Is this OK? =D

Comment: After composing cakephp and before git init, my directory already have a .gitignore file, with the following content: /vendor/* , /config/app.php , /tmp/* , /logs/* . Should I delete it or ignore it and run git init? After git init, vendor should be the only thing in this file?

Comment: if vendor is already ignored then you should be OK. You'll want to leave the other stuff that's in there if they're pertinent to your application.